# Getting variables from run line when using Java SQL

Tags: java, sql, database

So for example lets say I used the console line

`java AddPerson -c <sin>  -g <gender>  -age <age> -y <year>  [-w <when>]`

The inputs can be in any order and the -w input is optional.

My goal is to take these variables and add them to a database but I cant figure out how to
find and store the inputted variables.

This is the 'pseudo-code' for what I have.

```
public AddPerson (String[] args) {

//connection to db

public boolean newPerson(){
}

       }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can pass arguments to java main method as below

AddPerson has to be a class containing main method

```
java AddPerson "valueOfSin" "Male" "30" "2021" "yesterday"
```

Comment: Im wondering how I would store those inputs, even if  they were out of order (the -c, -g, -age specifies which entry it will be)

Comment: you can use commons-cli to pass and parse named arguments  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html